# Azure - Concurrent call - Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I'm trying to debug an Azure Service Bus.

What i do:

```
            long countOpen = namespaceManager.GetQueue(queueStrOpen).MessageCount;
            long countClose = namespaceManager.GetQueue(queueStrClose).MessageCount;
            QClientOpen = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueStrOpen, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
            QClientClose = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueStrClose, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);


                if (countOpen > 0)
                {
                    QClientOpen.OnMessage(OnMessageOpen,eventDrivenMessagingOptions);
                }
                if (countClose > 0)
                {
                    QClientClose.OnMessage(OnMessageClose,eventDrivenMessagingOptions);
                }
```

What my error is:

```
Exception: Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServerBusyException: Maximum number of
 concurrent receive requests is exceeded on entity '*****:QUEUE:ORDERSPRAC'.
 The limit is '5000'. Error code : 50004.TrackingId:63eefddf-0503-4c30-a2de-55fe
 450ac83c_G4_B21,TimeStamp:5/28/2014 12:57:30 PM.f71029ea-23c6-4ad0-8360-8b27818c
 9046_G4 ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Maximum number of concurrent receive requests is exceeded on entity '*****:QUEUE:ORDERSPRAC'. The limit is '5000'. Error code : 50004.TrackingId:63e efddf-0503-4c30-a2de 55fe450ac83c_G4_B21,TimeStamp:5/28/2014 12:57:30 PM.f71029ea-23c6-4ad0-8360-8b27818c9046_G4

 Server stack trace:
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequest SessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(Message wcfMessage)
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequest SessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)
```

This error don't pop everytime. It's just sometimes an Error is catch (the one above).
How and Why does this message appear whereas I Check IF my messages count are bigger than 0.

It shouldn't make a concurent receive call, but it does and after some day and a lot of IF condition, a lot of google search I'm out of idea.

Comment: Can you please share the value you set for "MaxConcurrentCalls" property in the OnMessageOptions (eventDrivenMessagingOptions from your sample above). This option determines the number of concurrent receive calls made to the service.

Comment: Are you creating many `QueueClient` instances?